# Instagram: How to get a brand new token for another user

Tags: ios, oauth, token, instagram, instagram-api

I am working on an iOS app that uses Instagram Integration.  I am able to have everything working.  The on thing I just noticed though, once I've called:

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

and received my token, let's say another user wants to login using the same device, I will need another token for that user.  The problem I am having is that when I call https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token subsequent times, it is not bringing up the IG login screen.  It automatically authenticates the existing token and redirects to the user page.

Is there soem kind of parameter that can be included in the URL call to force instagram to bring up the login screen, so another user can authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting cookies will log the user out. It looks like you are asking for iOS:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: Took me a few mins to convert this to swift.  But I just tried this and this login screen still redirects automatically.  This is what I have:  var cookie: NSHTTPCookie = NSHTTPCookie()
        var storage: NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
        var storageCookie = storage.cookies as [NSHTTPCookie]
        for cookie in storageCookie {
            storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }

Comment: If I don't find a solution, my work around for now works.  It's not seamless, but it does the job.  My work around right now is I am manually calling the Instagram Logout URL, then the user has to come back to my app and re-trigger the login screen again.  So it's a 2 step process right now.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer should work for you. You just need to add the following statement at the end.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Here is the full Swift code for deleting all cookies:

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
if let cookies = storage.cookies {
    for cookie in cookies as [NSHTTPCookie] {
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```